# PHP While loop Update stopping at first row

Tags: php

I made a while loop that will tell if there are items in the transaction history and will put it back in the inventory as the transaction ends but the problem is. It fetches an error called

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool in

So I tried the query's one by one and it works.

I tried to experiment and comment the other query and adding a counter++; to tell if the loop works. The problem I found is that after the first if else the counter only add's 1 Where as if I only try this it loops 4 which is right

Query I tried to check the number of loops

```
$counter=0;
$sql="SELECT * FROM brb_backtransaction WHERE trans_uk='$curr_trans' ";
if($rs=$con->query($sql)){
    while ($row=$rs->fetch_assoc()){
    $counter++
}
}
```

It echoes 1234 so it's correct but when the first if else happen it only echo'es 1

```
$counter =0;
$sql="SELECT * FROM brb_backtransaction WHERE trans_uk='$curr_trans' ";
if($rs=$con->query($sql)){
    while ($row=$rs->fetch_assoc()){
        $item = $row['trans_item'];
        $quan = $row['trans_quantity'];

        
    
        $sqlsitem="SELECT itmQuantity FROM brb_inventory WHERE itmName='$item'";
        if($rs=$con->query($sqlsitem)){
            $quanrow = $rs->fetch_assoc();
            $currquan = $quanrow['itmQuantity'];

            $counter++;
        }
```

I remove other query's as I think this is the problem I ran a total of 3 queries in the while loop.

Comment: You seem to be overwriting the value of the `$rs` variable with a totally new query.

Comment: is it not allowed? I've tried it on my other webpage it works

Comment: It could be allowed if you do not need to go back to the previous one. However, in your case, the while loop is expecting to find the previous query which is now thrown away.

Comment: I'll try to change the $rs variable one by one per called query

Comment: Just create a new variable for your second query such as `$rs2` (or anything else you want to call it). Also, don't forget to change it on the line immediately following as well.

Comment: Also, I haven't seen the rest of your code, but it looks like it is open to SQL injection attacks. So do not use it on a public or professional website or something you would be worried about getting hacked. You may want to look at prepared statements and PDO. In general, you should never use `$` variables in an SQL statement.

Comment: You shouldn't be using PHP to loop through recordsets to perform more queries. You should structure your query to return all the data you want in one query. Take a look at SQL JOINS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your while loop to work it needs access to your original data stream as stored in the `$rs` variable.

However, further down in your code you are replacing the contents of the `$rs` variable with a totally new data stream. Therefore, the while loop no longer has access to the original data stream as it is basically throw away.

To solve this, change the second instance to another variable name such as `$rs2`. That way you have two completely different variables for two different data streams.

With that said, your code is also open to injection attacks. I would recommend looking into PDO and prepared statements.

Also, Tangentially Perpendicular is correct in using SQL JOINS